# Which encryption algorithm for cloud backup?

Tags: gnupg, key-generation, ecc

I want to backup my data to the cloud. Before that, I want to encrypt it using GPG (`gpg (GnuPG) 2.2.11` and `libgcrypt 1.8.4`).

1. The backup is just for me, so I don't care about interoperability
2. I only care about how secure it is, especially in long-term, thinking about Quantum computers etc. (assuming the risk that data that was once uploaded, could be kept - even though it's deleted from a end user perspective - and might be decrypted later).

Which algorithm should I use in this case? ECCs? Which one? Does it make sense to double encrypt, e.g. first use RSA, then an ECC algorithm?

Update:
I understand that there is likely no solution that will be safe forever, as time might bring more computation power. But from today's view, which algorithm would be the most promising one to be broken as last one?

Comment: It will not be safe forever. Please limit the use case to be more realistic and to have more detail, i.e. how long do the data really need to be safe, how much will the data be worth to an attacker, i.e. how much effort will be done to get access to the data, what kind of usability you expect from the solution (more secure means usually less usability).

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. It's just my private data which I want to encrypt as a matter of principle. I want to encrypt the data using GPG, that's actually my usability requirement.

Comment: While this does not really provide the information I've asked for I would summarize this as that you only need to protect the data against somebody which would stumble over the data and will not waste much resources for decryption. And the data are likely irrelevant in 10 years anyway or might have been already leaked otherwise. In this case you could just use standard GPG settings.

Comment: You are right, I only require protection against someone stumbling over it. I should have asked the question in a different way. I will create a new question for that.